# Error installing "node-red-contrib-freeboard"

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi3, node-red, freeboard

I have installed node-red successfully.Its working,
But now i want to install "node-red-contrib-freeboard".

But when i hit the "npm install node-red-contrib-freeboard" command in my node red root directory I get this error:

```
node-red-contrib-freeboard@0.0.7 postinstall /root/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-freeboard
> node rewritefiles.js

{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/freeboard/index.html'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'node_modules/freeboard/index.html' }
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/freeboard/js/freeboard.js'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'node_modules/freeboard/js/freeboard.js' }
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/freeboard/plugins/thirdparty/jquery.keyframes.min.js'
npm WARN node-red-project@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN node-red-project@0.0.1 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-red-contrib-freeboard@0.0.7 postinstall: `node rewritefiles.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-red-contrib-freeboard@0.0.7 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-12-05T16_35_42_862Z-debug.log
```

Please help me to make it run.How do I resolve this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like in issue with version 0.0.7

https://github.com/urbiworx/node-red-contrib-freeboard/issues/28

try installing the previous version and see if the issue still occurs. check back on the github issue to see when it is corrected.

Comment: I have installed version 0.0.5 and It runs! Thank you!

Comment: no problem! just mark the answer as completed please.